# How to get an arrayJSON in webService Rest?

Tags: java, arrays, json, web-services, netbeans

I am developing a WEb Service Rest in java, netbeans.

This is the JSON I want to receive:

```
{
    "ticket":"2132158645161654561651616",
    "avaliacoes":[
        {
        "id":1,
        "nome":"Atendimento",
        "nota":5,
        "observacoes":"testeTEste"
        },
        {
        "id":2,
        "nome":"Atendimento",
        "nota":5,
        "observacoes":"testeTEste"
        }

    ]

}
```

Reception Class

```
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("venda/enviardados")
    public String postVenda(@QueryParam("key") String key, @QueryParam("serial") String serial, VendaAvaliacao va) {

...
}
```

Entity Classes

```
public class VendaAvaliacao {

    private int id;
    private String ticket;
    //private List<VendaAvaliacaoInner> avaliacoes = new ArrayList<>();  //I've tried it too
    private VendaAvaliacaoInner[] teste;

}

public class VendaAvaliacaoInner {

    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private int nota;
    private String observacao;

}
```

The ticket is received and populated, but array = null.

I've read other similar topics but they did not help .... how can I do?

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6046/convers%C3%A3o-de-string-json-para-objeto-java?rq=1

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159725/receber-valor-de-array-json-para-string-java

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/290759/como-obter-objetos-de-um-array-de-json-usando-jsonarray-no-java

Comment: Maybe the service REST you are consuming don't populate the data in the array. 

As an advice i would work with `List<T>` rather than `T[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the service REST you are consuming don't populate the data in the array.

As an advice i would work with `List<T>` rather than `T[]`

Also i see that you are mapping 3 properties in you object but the `id` property don't exist in raw JSON isn't it ?